# VBA DeleteFromArray Function

Tags: arrays, vba

I want to open a txt-File, read the textlines into arrays, delete specific arrays and write all those textlines into another textfile.

It might be easier to understand if you read the code:

**Sub:**

```
Open "G:\Arbeit\gen molding\Molding.spf" For Input As #1  'code from textfile below

Dim i As Integer
Dim tlmold() As String

Do Until EOF(1)                'read into array
    ReDim Preserve tlmold(i)
    Line Input #1, tlmold(i)
    i = i + 1
Loop
Close #1

DeleteFromArray tlmold, "M17"      'function code below
DeleteFromArray tlmold, "I_R828"
*DeleteFromArray tlmold, "I_R872"*

Dim tllength As Integer
tllength = UBound(tlmold)

For i = tllength To 0 Step -1       'newtext is the text for the new txt-file
  newtext = newtext & tlmold(i) & vbCrLf
Next i


newtext = Replace(newtext, "ÿþ", "")   'remove BOM

Set Fileout = fso.CreateTextFile("G:\Arbeit\gen molding\Molding2.spf", True, True)           'create new textfile
Fileout.Write newtext
Fileout.Close
```

**Function:**

```
Function DeleteFromArray(ByRef Arr As Variant, StringToBeDeleted As String)

Dim arrlength As Integer
Dim strtest As String

arrlength = UBound(Arr)
strtest = StringToBeDeleted

For i = 0 To arrlength
strtest = Arr(i)
 If InStr(strtest, StringToBeDeleted) <> 0 Then
    Arr(i) = ""
   ReDim Preserve Arr(arrlength - 1)
   Exit Function
 End If
Next i

End Function
```

**Textfile "MOLDING.SPF":**

```
G01          Z=0.1
G01 X=24.371 Z=-0.886
G03 X=24.370 Z=-1.040 CR=15.075
G01 X=24.126 Z=-12.934
G02 X=24.121 Z=-13.232 CR=50.500
G01 X=I_R830 *Z=-I_R872* ;MOLDING END PT
G01          *Z=-I_R872*-1.200
G01 X=I_R828
M17
```

The problem is while deleting *I_R872* from the textfile, my function does not`ReDim` the array a second time.
Because *I_R872* is two times in the textfile.
So the array `tlmold(5)`, which shouldn't  exist, is just empty.

I hope you understand my "code" and can help me with my problem.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Your `Exit Function` is what is preventing it from deleting all copies of the string, but the reason it is leaving blanks is because you set `Arr(i) = ""` (i.e. blank) and then remove the **last** entry from the array.

Comment: Do you require the **order** of the array to be preserved?  A simple fix would be to set `Arr(i) = Arr(arrLength)` (and change the looping slightly so that it wouldn't increment after a replacement such as that), but that will change the order.  To preserve the order, all positions after the match need to be shifted (and the looping still has to be changed so that it doesn't increment after a match)

Comment: (Of course, a simpler fix would be to simply not put unwanted data into the `tlmold` array to start with - i.e. only add it to that array if it doesn't contain one of the unwanted strings.)

Comment: 1. If I dont dont exit the function I get 'Subscript out of range (Error 9)' because my array-length doesnt match anymore.  2. Yes I need it to stay in order

Comment: That can be fixed by changing the loop to be a `Do While i < UBound(Arr)` style of loop

Comment: How many different strings need to be excluded?  Less than 30?

Comment: Can you give me an example of that `Do While i < UBound(Arr)` Loop? I tried that and got an endless loop  Yes, less than 30.

Comment: If less than 30, it is easiest to set up an array of unwanted text, and then just loop through those values as you read the data in.  That way you are only ever having to worry about the last position of the `tlmold` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish what you are trying to do is simply not to place the unwanted text into the array in the first place:

```
Open "G:\Arbeit\gen molding\Molding.spf" For Input As #1  'code from textfile below

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim tlmold() As String
Dim lineIn as String
Dim wanted As Boolean
Dim unwantedText
unwantedText = Array("M17","I_R828","I_R872")

Do Until EOF(1)                'read into array
    'Read an input line
    Line Input #1, lineIn
    'Now decide whether we want that record
    wanted = True
    For j = LBound(unwantedText) To UBound(unwantedText)
        If InStr(lineIn, unwantedText(j)) > 0 Then
            wanted = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    'If we want this record, re-dimension the array and store the value
    If wanted Then
        ReDim Preserve tlmold(i)
        tlmold(i) = lineIn
        i = i + 1
    End If
Loop
Close #1

Dim tllength As Integer
'...
```

Comment: Just realised one issue with the code I wrote - if the very first record contains something unwanted, the `ReDim` will crash because it will try to `ReDim Preserve tlmold(-1)` - I need to think about that one a bit more

Comment: Wow, thats simple... Thank you!

Comment: OK - updated the code to handle an unwanted first record.  (That's closer to how I would normally write the code, but I was originally trying to avoid setting up my normal `lineIn` variable as a temporary string.)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to bypass arrays and loops is to work with the entire text of the file

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub UpdateFile()

    Const FPATH = "G:\Arbeit\gen molding\"
    Const SRC_FILE = FPATH & "Molding.spf"
    Const DST_FILE = FPATH & "Molding2.spf"

    Dim fullFile As String

    Open SRC_FILE For Binary As #1
    fullFile = Space$(LOF(1))       'Read entire file into variable fullFile
    Get #1, , fullFile
    Close #1

    fullFile = Replace(fullFile, "M17", vbNullString)
    fullFile = Replace(fullFile, "I_R828", vbNullString)
    fullFile = Replace(fullFile, "ÿþ", vbNullString)

    Open DST_FILE For Output As #1
    Print #1, fullFile              'Write contents back to the new file
    Close #1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `newtext = Join(tlmold,vbCrLf)` is much faster than the loop below:

```
For i = tllength To 0 Step -1       'newtext is the text for the new txt-file
  newtext = newtext & tlmold(i) & vbCrLf
Next i
```

You could also use the **Scripting.FileSystemObject** to read the file.  I refactored your code using a **StringBuilder** instead of an array.  **StringBuilders** are optimized for concatenating strings.

---

```
Sub CreateNewSPF()
    Const SPF_FILENAME1 = "G:\Arbeit\gen molding\Molding.spf"
    Const SPF_FILENAME2 = "G:\Arbeit\gen molding\Molding2.spf"
    Const ForReading = 1
    Const ForWriting = 2
    Dim lineIn As String
    Dim fso As Object, StringBuilder As Object, TextStream1 As Object

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set StringBuilder = CreateObject("System.Text.StringBuilder")
    Set TextStream1 = fso.OpenTextFile(SPF_FILENAME1, ForReading)

    Do Until TextStream1.AtEndOfStream
        lineIn = TextStream1.ReadLine
        If isValidSPF(lineIn) Then StringBuilder.Append_3 lineIn & vbCrLf
    Loop

    TextStream1.Close

    StringBuilder.Replace "ÿþ", ""

    Set Fileout = fso.CreateTextFile(SPF_FILENAME2, True, True)    'create new textfile
    Fileout.Write StringBuilder.ToString
    Fileout.Close

End Sub

Function isValidSPF(lineIn As String) As Boolean
    Dim v As Variant
    For Each v In Array("M17", "I_R828", "I_R872")
        If InStr(1, lineIn, v, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then Exit Function
    Next
    isValidSPF = True
End Function
```